# Merge 2 files which have Json objects using Jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a requirement where in 2 parameter files needs to be merged to one using Jq

```
param1.json
[
   "name=xyz",
   "age=40",
   "email=qqqq"
]
```

```
param2.json
[
  "name=xyz",
  "age=42",
  "drivingLicense=2761"
]
```

I need a resultant value to be

```
[
  "name=xyz",
  "age=42",
  "email=qqqq",
  "drivingLicense=2761"
]
```

When I try to use Jq add **jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' param1.json param2.json** the resultant

```
[
  "name=xyz",
  "age=40",
  "email=qqqq",
  "name=xyz",
  "age=42",
  "drivingLicense=2761"
]
```

I tried using **jq '. * input' param1.json param2.json** but that is not working either
What is the best way to merge them
TIA

Comment: What you have tried is meant to merge objects, not arrays. In your case, you would need to destructure your array items in order to match on the string part before the `=` sign.

Answer (score 0):

This approach makes use of the circumstance that object field names are unique. On collision, latter items overwrite former ones.

```bash
jq -s '[add | with_entries(.key = (.value | .[:index("=")]))[]]'
```

```json
[
  "name=xyz",
  "age=42",
  "email=qqqq",
  "drivingLicense=2761"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vmn7g_EDtlw)

Note: Instead of `add` you can, of course, still use `.[0] + .[1]` or `. + input` (the latter without `-s`).

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert your arrays into objects, then `add` those objects together; then convert to an array again:

```bash
$ jq -s 'map(map(./"="|{(first):.[1:]|join("=")})|add)|add|to_entries|map(join("="))' param1.json  param2.json
[
  "name=xyz",
  "age=42",
  "email=qqqq",
  "drivingLicense=2761"
]
```

If your values cannot contain an equal sign, then `{(first):.[1:]|join("=")}` can be simplified to `{(first):last}`.

Or merging the arrays to one big array before converting to objects:

```
add
|map(./"="|{(first):.[1:]|join("=")})
|add
|to_entries
|map(join("="))
```

Answer (score 0):

Levaraging the fact that this can be reformulated as a grouping problem, you can group by the "key" of your string, then select the last item in each group (A [reusable function to build group objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73893818/112968) can help but is not required).

```bash
$ jq -s 'add | map(./"=") | group_by(first) | map(last|join("="))' param1.json param2.json
[
  "age=42",
  "drivingLicense=2761",
  "email=qqqq",
  "name=xyz"
]
```